# Run SKAction that runs a void statement SpriteKit

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit, void, skaction

I'm trying to run a particle node or just a node when an action is called but Im unsure of **which action** to use or if I'm even doing it right.

I've searched apple's docs with no luck.

This is what I've attempted:

```
    -(void)setupbabyFireNode{
    NSString *babyFirePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"BabyOnFireParticle" ofType:@"sks"];

    babyFireNode = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:babyFirePath];

    babyFireNode.position = CGPointMake(-30, 40);
    babyFireNode.zPosition = 1;

    [babyNode addChild:babyFireNode];
    }

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [babyNode removeActionForKey:@"left"];

     babyNode.position = CGPointMake(700, 280);

     moveLeft = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(100, 280)duration:5.0];


    SKAction *completion = [SKAction runBlock:^{

    SKScene *endScene = [[EndScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:5];
    [self.view presentScene:endScene transition:doors];

    }];
    SKAction *fire = [self setupbabyFireNode];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ moveLeft ,fire, completion ]];


    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ moveLeft ,completion ]];

    [babyNode runAction:sequence withKey:@"left"];

    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate what you are trying to do, along with what you have tried.

Comment: I would like to add a node, to the scene, within an action sequence. (node appears after it moves left)  I've created the node and it all works fine. I can add the node to the scene using [self setupNode]; .  "What I've tried is" (  SKAction *action = [self setUpFireNode];  )  "LOL", and called it in a sequence with an SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[ moveLeft ,[self setUpFireNode... etc..], completion ]];
    
[Node runAction:sequence];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, this is what you are trying to do;

```
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveLeft ,[SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnPipes) onTarget:self]]];

[Node runAction:sequence];
```

Comment: You gonna change the selector which takes function name as a parameter, so you need something like; [self runAction:[SKAction performSelector:@selector(setUpBabyFireNode) onTarget:self]];

Comment: Thank you!!  I'll edit my code shortly.  Sorry for deleting old comment.  Realized this is the correct answer.